# Timer in Java with GUI

Tags: java, swing, timer, gui

I have created a timer with GUI in Java.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Counter {
   private JButton button;
   private JFormattedTextField hours;
   private JFormattedTextField minutes;
   private JFormattedTextField seconds;

   private Timer timer;
   private int delay = 1000;
   private ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                   if(sec >= 1) {
                       sec = sec - 1;
                       seconds.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                   }
                   else if(sec == 0 && min > 0) {
                       sec = 59;
                       min = min - 1;
                       seconds.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                       minutes.setText(String.valueOf(min));
                   }
                   else if(min == 0 && hrs > 0) {
                       sec = 59;
                       min = 59;
                       hrs = hrs - 1;
                       seconds.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                       minutes.setText(String.valueOf(min));
                       hours.setText(String.valueOf(hrs));
                   }
                   if(hrs == 0 && min == 0 && sec == 0) {
                       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Countdown ended!","Ende", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
                       timer.stop();
                   }
       }
   };

   private int hrs;
   private int min;
   private int sec;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Counter::new);
   }

   Counter() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(300, 200);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
       JPanel subpanel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 3));

       /* 
        * The following lines ensure that the user can 
        * only enter numbers.
       */

       NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
       NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
       formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
       formatter.setMinimum(0);
       formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
       formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
       formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

       //"labeling"

       JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
       text1.setText("hours:");
       text1.setEditable(false);

       JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
       text2.setText("minutes:");
       text2.setEditable(false);


       JTextField text3 = new JTextField();
       text3.setText("seconds:");
       text3.setEditable(false);

       //fields for minutes and seconds
       hours = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
       minutes = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
       seconds = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
       hours.setText("0");
       minutes.setText("0");
       seconds.setText("0");

       JPanel subpanel2 = new JPanel();

       /*
        * When the user presses the OK-button, the program will
        * start to count down.
       */

       button = new JButton("OK");
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
               hrs = Integer.valueOf(hours.getText());
               min = Integer.valueOf(minutes.getText());
               sec = Integer.valueOf(seconds.getText());
               button.setEnabled(false);

               //Timer for one second delay
               Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
               timer.start();  


           }
       });

       //Reset-button
       JButton button2 = new JButton("Reset");
       button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
               hours.setText("0");
               minutes.setText("0");
               seconds.setText("0");
               button.setEnabled(true);
               hrs = 0;
               min = 0;
               sec = 0;
           }
       });

       subpanel1.add(text1);
       subpanel1.add(text2);
       subpanel1.add(text3);
       subpanel1.add(hours);
       subpanel1.add(minutes);
       subpanel1.add(seconds);
       subpanel2.add(button);
       subpanel2.add(button2);
       panel.add(subpanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       panel.add(subpanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
       frame.add(panel);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on improving the code!

Comment: Please tell us more about the purpose of the code. It's a timer, ok, timing what? What is it supposed to do? What prompted you to write this?

Comment: It doesn't have any special purpose. It was just for fun. I know that this answer doesn't really help, but I can't give a better one.

Comment: I don't like global imports: `javax.swing.*` I can't tell what sort of Timer you have.  There's java.util.Timer and java.swing.Timer, and it isn't obvious which one you're using.  Please don't use global imports like this.

Comment: @markspace - I would say the difference between `java.util` and `javax.swing` is pretty easy to see, especially when only one of them is being imported.  Also, as in this case, it seems to me that using a global is better than adding a lot of extra lines to the imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

Quite a few of your variables can be marked `final`.  From my understanding pretty much any variable where the underlying object doesn't get reassigned to a new object.

Instead of 3 separate variable for the time parts, you could use `java.time.LocalTime` to hold the time parts.  Not only does this reduce your code, but it simplifies the count down portion in that subtracting 1 second will adjust the other fields automatically.

Since `Integer.valueOf` uses `Integer.parseInt` anyway, I think it would be better, in this case, to use `Integer.parseInt`

You misspelled the title of the message dialog when the countdown is done.

I think `INFORMATION_MESSAGE` is a better icon, for the message dialog, than `CANCEL_OPTION`, in this case.

The `throws` clause in the `main` declaration is redundant.

With these adjustments your code could look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Counter {
    private final JButton button;
    private final JFormattedTextField hours;
    private final JFormattedTextField minutes;
    private final JFormattedTextField seconds;

    private final Timer timer;
    private final int delay = 1000;
    private final ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            time = time.minusSeconds(1);
            if (time.equals(LocalTime.MIN)) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Countdown ended!", "Ended", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                timer.stop(); 
            }
            seconds.setText(String.valueOf(time.getSecond()));
            minutes.setText(String.valueOf(time.getMinute()));
            hours.setText(String.valueOf(time.getHour()));
        }
    };

    private LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Counter::new);
    }

    Counter() {
        timer = new Timer(delay,taskPerformer);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 3));

        /*
         * The following lines ensure that the user can
         * only enter numbers.
         */

        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
        formatter.setMinimum(0);
        formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);

        //"labeling"

        JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
        text1.setText("hours:");
        text1.setEditable(false);

        JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
        text2.setText("minutes:");
        text2.setEditable(false);


        JTextField text3 = new JTextField();
        text3.setText("seconds:");
        text3.setEditable(false);

        //fields for minutes and seconds
        hours = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        minutes = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        seconds = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        hours.setText("0");
        minutes.setText("0");
        seconds.setText("0");

        JPanel subPanel2 = new JPanel();

        /*
         * When the user presses the OK-button, the program will
         * start to count down.
         */

        button = new JButton("OK");
        button.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            time = LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(hours.getText()), Integer.parseInt(minutes.getText()), Integer.parseInt(seconds.getText()));
            button.setEnabled(false);
            //Timer for one second delay
            timer.start();
        });

        //Reset-button
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Reset");
        button2.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            hours.setText("0");
            minutes.setText("0");
            seconds.setText("0");
            button.setEnabled(true);
            time = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0);
            timer.stop();
        });

        subPanel1.add(text1);
        subPanel1.add(text2);
        subPanel1.add(text3);
        subPanel1.add(hours);
        subPanel1.add(minutes);
        subPanel1.add(seconds);
        subPanel2.add(button);
        subPanel2.add(button2);
        panel.add(subPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(subPanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please rename the **magic number** `delay = 1000`?